# Slow dynamic button add/remove in C#

Tags: c#, performance

I’am switching between buttons by adding/removing them dynamically. After 20 switches the whole application starts to be more and more slow.

It seem’s It is related to function Dispose(). When I use it the problem become worst. You can see how I used it in pasted code.

I’am using Visual Studio 2010 Express.

Any idea what I’am doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tracker
{
    public partial class Tracker : Form
    {

        Button New_Trace = new Button();
        Button Continue_Trace = new Button();
        Button Save_Trace = new Button();

        Button New_Point = new Button();
        Button Exit_Trace = new Button();


        public Tracker()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Init_Menu1();
        }


        public void Init_Menu1()
        {


            New_Trace.Left = 20;
            New_Trace.Top = 40;
            New_Trace.Text = "New Trace";
            this.New_Trace.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.New_Trace_Click);
            this.Controls.Add(New_Trace);

            Continue_Trace.Left = 100;
            Continue_Trace.Top = 40;
            Continue_Trace.Text = "Cont. Trace";
            this.Continue_Trace.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Continue_Trace_Click);
            this.Controls.Add(Continue_Trace);

            Save_Trace.Left = 180;
            Save_Trace.Top = 40;
            Save_Trace.Text = "Save Trace";
            this.Save_Trace.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Save_Trace_Click);
            this.Controls.Add(Save_Trace);
        }

        public void Init_Menu2()
        {


            New_Point.Left = 20;
            New_Point.Top = 40;
            New_Point.Text = "New Point";
            this.New_Point.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.New_Point_Click);
            this.Controls.Add(New_Point);

            Exit_Trace.Left = 180;
            Exit_Trace.Top = 40;
            Exit_Trace.Text = "Exit";
            this.Exit_Trace.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.Exit_Trace_Click);
            this.Controls.Add(Exit_Trace);

        }

        public void remove_Menu1()
        {

            if (this.Controls.Contains(New_Trace))
            {
                // this.New_Trace.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.New_Trace_Click);
                this.Controls.Remove(New_Trace);
                //New_Trace.Dispose();
            }

            if (this.Controls.Contains(Continue_Trace))
            {
                // this.Continue_Trace.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.Continue_Trace_Click);
                this.Controls.Remove(Continue_Trace);
                //Continue_Trace.Dispose();
            }

            if (this.Controls.Contains(Save_Trace))
            {
                // this.Save_Trace.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.Save_Trace_Click);
                this.Controls.Remove(Save_Trace);
                //Save_Trace.Dispose();
            }

        }

        public void remove_Menu2()
        {
            if (this.Controls.Contains(New_Point))
            {
                //this.New_Point.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.New_Point_Click);
                this.Controls.Remove(New_Point);
                //New_Point.Dispose();
            }

            if (this.Controls.Contains(Exit_Trace))
            {
                //this.Exit_Trace.Click -= new System.EventHandler(this.Exit_Trace_Click);
                this.Controls.Remove(Exit_Trace);
                //Exit_Trace.Dispose();
            }

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void New_Trace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            remove_Menu1();
            Init_Menu2();

        }


        private void Continue_Trace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void Save_Trace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void New_Point_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }


        private void Exit_Trace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            remove_Menu2();
            Init_Menu1();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of deleting and recreating each object, have you tried setting the button's visibility property to false/true to hide/show the buttons?

Comment: Visual Studio includes expert tools such as profiling tools to help you diagnose such problems.

Comment: I was thinking about it, but from this perspective it would be more efective to use one button and change its function in code. (buttons are at the same place and size).

Comment: You could do that.  In my experience it gets a little hard to read with all the extra if statements vs 2 methods listing out the controls and hiding/showing what you want.  Actually, you could do one method which accepts a bool visibility, then set `button.Visibility=(visibility)` or `button.Visibility=(!visibility)`  (I usually surround Boolean statements with () so it is easier to tell they are Booleans.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing visible of button to false/true instead of deleting and recreating it.

```
button.Visible = true; //set visible to visible
button.Visible = false; //set visible to invisible
button.Visible = !(button.Visible); //set visible to visible if button was invisible or to invisible, if button was Visible
```

Also In VS 2015 you have profiling tools, which can help you (but I'm not sure If they're in VS 2010 too)

Please, mark my answer as correct, if I helped you :D

Comment: While this is a good work around, it does not answer the actual question which is regarding performance issues related to creating and destroying many buttons at once.